# remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'repo_name not found

Tags: git

I have run into a bit of a problem here, I have been added as a collaborator(I have double checked it) to a private repository and hence technically, I should be able to have access to the repository. But when I try to clone the repository into my local machine. I get the error mentioned in the title. I have searched for other options, but they don't solve the problem either. What am I missing out on?

Here is the stack trace :

```
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ git --version
git version 2.2.1
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ git clone https://github.com/Giblib/giblib.git
Cloning into 'giblib'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Giblib/giblib.git/' not found.
```

Comment: Try cloning using ssh.

Comment: @khrm : I am thinking of the same thing too. Is there any tutorial that I can use to do such a thing?

Comment: Try git clone git@github.com:Giblib/giblib.git

Comment: I will need to set up the ssh keys for that right? It wouldn't work otherwise

Comment: Yes. https://help.github.com/categories/ssh/

Comment: Write this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem, One can still clone the required repo through the HTTPS method by providing `git clone 'username@github.com/../git_repository.git` in the command line.

It worked out well for me and I was able to access the private repository.